# How to create struct in Xcode, work with levels in struct and read them into a new function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct

I have a little issue with struct in swift. First of all, I'm new in developing apps, but I'm doing my best to learn. 
A few days ago, I've posted my code and someone told me it was better to use struc and work on levels, but to be honest..it's about 4 days that I'm looking on the web how to work with structs..but I can't figure it out how..

I'm posting here the code...and I hope someone will illuminate me how to adjust the code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var rightImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sh: UIImageView!

enum correctImageType {
    case left, right
}

struct Level {
    var word: String
    var leftImage: UIImage
    var rightImage: UIImage
    var soundFile: String
    var correctImage: correctImageType

    init(word: String, leftImage: UIImage, rightImage: UIImage, soundFile: String, correctImage: correctImageType) {
        self.word = word
        self.leftImage = leftImage
        self.rightImage = rightImage
        self.soundFile = soundFile
        self.correctImage = correctImage

    }

}

var level1 = Level(word: "dog", leftImage: UIImage(named: "foto1.png")!, rightImage: UIImage(named: "foto5.png")!, soundFile: "s1", correctImage: .left)
var level2 = Level(word: "horse", leftImage: UIImage(named: "foto5.png")!, rightImage: UIImage(named: "foto3.png")!, soundFile: "s5", correctImage: .right)


@IBAction func nextImage(_ sender: Any) {
    leftImage.image = level1.leftImage
    leftImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(leftImage)
    let gesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.singleTap1))
    leftImage.addGestureRecognizer(gesture1)



}
func singleTap1() {
    if correctImageType.left == level1.correctImage {

        print("ok")
    } else {

        print("not ok")
    }
}


var player: AVAudioPlayer!

@IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

So, what I'm trying to do here... When I click on the nextButton I'd like to show 2 images ( left and right ) and a button (playSound). The sound must be linked to one of the two images. My problem is..that I don't know how to make this happen.. I don't know how to work with a struct..

Comment: You have two questions here, in essence. "How do structs work?" and "What is wrong with my code?" You might want to post a separate question for each or edit your question so it asks one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a `struct` and a `class` in Swift is that structs have value semantics and classes have reference semantics:

[Value and Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

> Types in Swift fall into one of two categories: first, “value types”, where each instance keeps a unique copy of its data, usually defined as a `struct`, `enum`, or tuple. The second, “reference types”, where instances share a single copy of the data, and the type is usually defined as a `class`.

So if you create an instance of a `struct` in one variable and assign it to another variable you'll be able to chance the second variable without affecting the first. If, instead, it was a `class` then changing the second would change the first because each variable would be a reference to the actual storage.

Other than that both structs and classes are nearly identical. There are some differences in declaring things like `mutable` methods but they shouldn't affect what you're doing here.